# Django 2.0 Redirect with kwargs

Tags: django, django-urls

I am a trying to pass kwargs but I think I have a URL path error?  I am using the updated Django 2 URLS.

```
return redirect ( 'enroll:select_prod', slug = e.slug, kwargs = { 'a': a, 'p': p, 's': s }   )
```

this is the URL urlpatterns:

```
path('select_prod/<slug:slug>/', views.select_prod,  name = 'select_prod' ),
```

And where it is redirected to:

```
def select_prod ( request, slug, *arg, **kwargs  ):
```

and this is the error I get

```
Reverse for 'select_prod' with keyword arguments '{'slug': 'cC1gBIk4Fwh7Nr5xRv', 'kwargs': {'a': '5', 'p': ['6', '7'], 's': []}}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['enroll\\/select_prod\\/(?P<slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\\/$']
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Keyword arguments are *not* optional in URL patterns as they are in Python functions. Your URL pattern doesn't expect `a`, `p`, and `s` keys.